# Simple subquery to slow on huge table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

so I got a mysql database with 2 tables, one (sd_clients) with about 24k entries:

```html
CREATE TABLE `sd_clients` (
  `ms_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `ms_share_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `short_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `standard_name` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `legal_name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1=Paid Client | 2=Non-Paid Client',
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `summary` text,
  `sector` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_sector` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `business_country` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_paid` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 = Non-Paid Client | 1=Paid Client',
  `description_en` text,
  `description_zh-hans` text,
  `description_zh-hant` text,
  `highlights_en` text,
  `highlights_zh-hans` text,
  `highlights_zh-hant` text,
  `logo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `summary_subsection_title_en` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `summary_subsection_title_zh-hans` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `summary_subsection_title_zh-hant` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `summary_subsection_text_en` text,
  `summary_subsection_text_zh-hans` text,
  `summary_subsection_text_zh-hant` text,
  `summary_short_en` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `summary_short_zh-hans` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `summary_short_zh-hant` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `other_information_en` text,
  `other_information_zh-hans` text,
  `other_information_zh-hant` text,
  `change_percentage` decimal(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_sector` bigint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_subsector` bigint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `background_info_en` text,
  `background_info_zh-hans` text,
  `background_info_zh-hant` text,
  `share_id_displayed` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ms_id`) KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1024,
  UNIQUE KEY `ms_id` (`ms_id`) KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1024,
  KEY `share_id_displayed` (`share_id_displayed`) KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1024
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

And another called sd_clients_daily_stocks, with about 50 million entries:

```html
CREATE TABLE `sd_clients_daily_stocks` (
  `ms_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `ms_share_id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `symbol` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exchange_id` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` bigint(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_low` decimal(19,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_high` decimal(19,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `market_cap` bigint(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open_price` decimal(19,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_price` decimal(19,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enterprise_value` bigint(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency_id` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valoren` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cusip` char(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isin` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sedol` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ipo_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_depositary_receipt` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `depositary_receipt_ratio` decimal(9,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `security_type` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `share_class_description` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `share_class_status` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_primary_share` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_dividend_reinvest` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_direct_invest` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `investment_id` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ipo_offer_price` decimal(19,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delisting_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `delisting_reason` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mic` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `common_share_sub_type` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ipo_offer_price_range` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exchange_sub_market_global_id` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conversion_ratio` decimal(19,9) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `ms_id` (`ms_id`) USING HASH,
  KEY `ms_share_id` (`ms_share_id`) USING HASH,
  KEY `symbol` (`symbol`),
  KEY `exchange_id` (`exchange_id`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

I'm trying to run a fairly simple query:

```html
SELECT DISTINCT
 sd_clients.ms_id, 
 sd_clients.standard_name, 
 sd_clients.is_paid, 
 sd_clients.logo,
 sd_clients.change_percentage,
 (
  SELECT 
   CONCAT(
     `exchange_id`, '|--|', 
     `symbol`, '|--|', 
     `close_price`, '|--|', 
     `day_low`, '|--|', 
     `day_high`
   ) as items
  FROM sd_clients_daily_stocks 
  WHERE ms_share_id = sd_clients.share_id_displayed 
  ORDER BY created_at DESC 
  LIMIT 1
 ) as company_data
FROM sd_clients 
GROUP BY ms_id 
ORDER BY sd_clients.standard_name ASC
LIMIT 10
```

But for some reason, it's taking way too long (like over 1 minute), to get any results, any idea why?

BTW, it works just fine if I remove the subquery, but I need it because the rest of the data, is in another table. Also, I know I could get the results without the subquery first, but I have other queries where the subquery must be there.

I also noticed that it gets blazing fast if I use a string instead of "sd_clients.share_id_displayed" on the subquery.

Comment: As well as CREATE TABLE statements, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN of same. And your GROUP BY clause is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

You should try an index on `sd_clients_daily_stocks(ms_share_id, created_at)`.

You can add the additional columns from the `select` if you want a covering index.

Comment: @BrunoPereira . . . One index with the two columns in the specified order.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off joining on a non-correlated subquery based off your current subquery; using this kind of technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30955692/4104224) to find the most recent rows for each in the new subquery.

---

Edit: I was thinking more something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sd_clients.ms_id, sd_clients.standard_name, sd_clients.is_paid, sd_clients.logo, sd_clients.change_percentage
    , scdsB.items
FROM sd_clients 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT scdsA.ms_share_id
        , CONCAT(
            scdsA.`exchange_id`, '|--|', scdsA.`symbol`, '|--|', 
            scdsA.`close_price`, '|--|', scdsA.`day_low`, '|--|', scdsA.`day_high`
        ) as items
    FROM sd_clients_daily_stocks AS scdsA
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ms_share_id, MAX(created_at)
        FROM sd_clients_daily_stocks
        GROUP BY ms_share_id 
    ) AS lasts
    ON scdsA.ms_share_id = lasts.ms_share_id
    AND scdsA.created_at = lasts.created_at
) scdsB 
ON sd_clients.share_id_displayed = scdsB.ms_share_id 
GROUP BY sd_clients.ms_id 
ORDER BY sd_clients.standard_name ASC 
LIMIT 10;
```

... But even this likely won't reduce the speed much more, if any, from the 12 seconds. At that point you are better off looking into indexes that could help. For example, the `lasts` grouping subquery that finds the most recent(max) `created_at` value for each `ms_share_id` value would benefit from an index on `sd_clients_daily_stocks (ms_shared_id, created_at)` as would the the JOIN it is used in.

Comment: I tried, it got down to about 12 seconds, still too long. `SELECT DISTINCT
 sd_clients.ms_id, 
 sd_clients.standard_name, 
 sd_clients.is_paid, 
 sd_clients.logo,
 sd_clients.change_percentage,
 scds.*
FROM sd_clients 
JOIN (
 SELECT 
  ms_share_id
 FROM sd_clients_daily_stocks 
 GROUP BY ms_share_id
) scds
ON sd_clients.share_id_displayed = scds.ms_share_id
GROUP BY sd_clients.ms_id 
ORDER BY sd_clients.standard_name ASC
LIMIT 10`